# Send Contact form 7 data to remote server using .NET api

Tags: plugins, plugin-contact-form-7, microsoft

**Problem**

- I want to send my wordpress form data to my .Net API. Link of my api
- http://remote.hhds.com.au:49172/API/api/addonlinebookings?jsonData=@test
- I am using Contact form 7 and also use contact form 7 to api plugin in wordpress.

**Error**

When form is submitted than error show in plugin

> Curl error: 7 Failed to connect to remote

[Error detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNVXk.png)

If i try to send form data to my api using jquery with simple input field for testing purpose still not get any response.

```
<form action="https://remote.hhds.com.au:49172/API/api/addonlinebookings? 
 jsonData=@test" id="myformID">
    <input type="text" name="fname">
    <input type="submit" name="Send">
 </form>



 $(document).ready(function($){
   $("form#myformID").on( "submit", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert("test");

    // Get some values from elements on the page:
    var $form = $( this ),
        $data = {
            FirstName: $form.find( "input[name='fname']" ).val()
        },
        url = $form.attr( "action" );

    // Send the data using post
    var posting = $.post( url, $data );

    posting.done(function( data ) {
        //Do whatever you need with the returned data here.
        console.log(data);
        alert(data);
    });

   });
 });
```

Comment: this server at https://remote.hhds.com.au:49172 returns an error `SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG`. the server configuration must be corrected : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119336/ssl-error-rx-record-too-long-and-apache-ssl

Comment: if you use the submit event then you are unable to validate your form fields.  Furthermore, it looks like the issue is with your POST request to the remote server and unrelated to the cf7 plugin perse.  Check the remote server to make sure it is working as expected.